# @RequestMapping error for RenderRequest

Tags: spring, request, portlet

I am trying to do `RequestMapping` for my portlet `RenderRequest`

```
    @RequestMapping("view.jsp", params="test")
public void doSome(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response){
    }
```

But I get multiple errors like

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ""view.jsp"", invalid MemberValuePairs
- The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
 RequestMapping
- RequestMapping cannot be resolved to a type
```

Why??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the value attribute. You also need to add an import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="view.jsp", params="test")
public void doSome(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response){
}
```